# Store long float MySQL

Tags: mysql

What kind of data type should I choose in MySQL to store digit like this 50.078294547389426

Comment: It depends.  What precision do you need?  Do you want binary or decimal?  How important is performance?  What do you know about the other values that will be in the field?

Comment: Even though the question is newer than this one, there is some good discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150274/difference-between-float-and-decimal-data-type

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-data-types.htm

Initially id look at float but id try to get more of an idea of what sort of data your looking at first.

Answer (score 0):

Use Float or double

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/problems-with-float.html