# mysql and php float data types

Tags: php, mysql

In my app i want save float or double values that are calculated using php into mysql.
I also want to make calculations with these columns in stored procedures using sql.
But i notice that double and float data types show different in php and mysql.
for example after a calculation in php i might get a value 4.00 while the same calculation is mysql is 4.0027.
How can i make possible to have more or less the same value calclated. what type should my columns in mysql be and what cast should i make in php?
Thanx

Comment: `4.0027` will display as `4.00` if you echo it using number_format() with a precision of 2, or round it to 2 decimal places somewhere in your code

Answer (score 0):

You may read [this page](http://0.30000000000000004.com/) for answers why sum of two integers often results in a float.

Considering the MySQL data type, the difference is discussed and explained in this question: [Difference between float and decimal data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150274/difference-between-float-and-decimal-data-type)

I would suggest to store in decimal with some rounding before insert/update in PHP.

Again, everything depends on the calculations you perform on the values.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

use `number_format("4.0024",2);`  output `4.00`

**or**  *Update*

use `number_format("6556564.0024",2, '.', '');` or `number_format(6556564.0024,2, '.', '');`  output `6556564.00`

Comment: yes but gives me back a string result. I still want a number with 2 decimal places