# Floating point inaccuracy in case

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple float column, that doesn't yield the correct value when selected via a `CASE`:

`SELECT my_column FROM my_table LIMIT 1;` yields 815.35
But `SELECT (CASE WHEN true THEN my_column ELSE 0 END) AS my_column FROM my_table LIMIT 1;` yields 815.3499755859375

Problem is obviously coming from the case and from the ELSE value (using 'test' rather than 0 works as intended, but using an other float does not)
I could solve it by using `ROUND(my_column,2)`, or using a decimal column instead of a float one, but I'd actually want to understand what's happening here

Comment: It is because you are using float type. Use decimal instead. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150274/difference-between-float-and-decimal-data-type

Comment: @karacsi_maci I probably will do it, and actually did talk about it in my question, but I don't understand why using a CASE is causing this inaccuracy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think @dasblinkenlight has explained the underlying issue with the representation.  Your question is also about the `CASE`.

A `CASE` *expression* returns a single type.  MySQL has to decide on the type when the query is compiled.

Your `CASE` is combining two different types, a `float` and an `int`. I believe that this should be returning a `float` value.

The rules leave me a bit confused as to why anything is happening; after all, a float to a float sounds like a no-op.  But, there are two representations for floats, 4-byte and 8-byte.  My guess is that your column is stored as a 4-byte `float`.  The SQL engine decides that the `CASE` expression should return an 8-byte `double`.  The conversion to the `double` is the cause of your issue.

In fact, [this](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cf8cd/1) little SQLFiddle confirms this guess.  The issue is a conversion to double.

Answer (score 2):

The value `815.35` has no exact representation as IEEE-754 `float`. The value that is actually stored in a `float` field is an approximation that depends on the number of bits used for the representation.

When you use single-precision `float`, the value becomes `815.3499755859375`, which is what you see printed when you run the query. You can compute the representation that you get with an IEEE-754 calculator (for example, [this one](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html)).

In order to avoid representation differences like this, use `decimal` data ty[e to represent values that need precise decimal representation, such as amounts of money.

Comment: Please suggest him to use decimals.

Comment: This is a good answer, but it doesn't explain why the query without the `CASE` is only producing two decimal points of precision.