# MySQL: Why is the date object always showing "0"?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a table with one column in date format. 
Below is my code for doing so:

```
CREATE TABLE Sales
    (`CustomerID` int, `mydate` date,  `amount` float(2))
;

INSERT INTO Sales
    (customerID, mydate, amount)
VALUES
    (10, 8/2/96,  2540.78),
    (20, 1/30/99, 1800.54),
    (30,7/14/95, 460.33), 
    (10, 6/29/98,2400),
    (50, 2/3/98, 600.28),
    (60, 3/2/98, 720),
    (10, 7/6/98, 150)
;
```

But my outcome is always:

```
10|0|2540.78                                                                                                                              
20|0|1800.54                                                                                                                              
30|0|460.33                                                                                                                               
10|0|2400.0                                                                                                                               
50|0|600.28                                                                                                                               
60|0|720.0                                                                                                                                
10|0|150.0
```

So basically the date column is only showing 0.

I am using this online IDE to help me execute this code (it's an online IDE executing MySQL I believe): https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_sql_online.php

I tried change the data type to "timestamp" or "datetime" but none of them work. 
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: mysql default date format for insert is YYYY-MM-DD so as a string so 8/2/96 would be '1996-8-2' this allows MySQL to implicitly cast the string to a date; otherwise the database is trying to do math by taking 8/2/96 and convert that to a date which seems to be returning 0.

Answer (score 4):

Use the proper mySQL date format and it should work..

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html

"...
The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part. MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'...."

```
INSERT INTO Sales
    (customerID, mydate, amount)
VALUES
    (10, '1996-8-2',  2540.78),
    (20, '1999-1-30', 1800.54),
    (30, '1995-7-14', 460.33), 
    (10, '1998-6-29', 2400),
    (50, '1998-2-3',  600.28),
    (60, '1998-3-2',   720),
    (10, '1998-7-6',   150)
```

On an additional note, ***don't store amounts (currency) as floats***.  Anything where you want a SPECIFIC number of decimals, and not have errors in floating point math, needs to be stored as NUMERIC or DECIMAL with scale and precision.  So instead of `amount float(2)` use  `amount numeric(10,2)` (set the 10 to the max value to left of decimals planned, and then add 5 is my rule. (3 because of growth 2 for the decimals (add more if you need more precision)  Assuming 8 values before decimal allowed and 2 decimals.

Simply put: ***Using floating point or double datatypes anytime you want a retain specific values for decimals is asking for trouble later.***

Think of using float and double datatypes when precision doesn't matter such as large numbers like 6.22*10^23  ([avagadro's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avogadro_constant)) typically don't care about anything after 6.22 Very large numbers or very small numbers in scientific arena's make sense but seldom if ever when dealing with currency where precision matters.

More on it:

- [Best data type to store money values in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13030368/best-data-type-to-store-money-values-in-mysql)
- [Difference between float and decimal data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150274/difference-between-float-and-decimal-data-type/37839277#37839277)
- [Difference between numeric, float and decimal in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056323/difference-between-numeric-float-and-decimal-in-sql-server/7158770#7158770) (sql server specific but relevant)
- [Difference between decimal, float and double in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-net)

Working [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/940f24/1)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, xQbert! But are the quotation marks around the dates required?

Comment: Yes, otherwise it is a mathematical expression ;)

Comment: Wow. good to know! I was definitely googling the wrong things. Thanks so much guys!!! :)

Comment: And thanks so much for the edit! then when do we use floats then?

Comment: Thank you so much @xQbert!! I thought float would be a number with decimal hence more accurate, or at least that's what I learned in Java. This is quite counterintuitive.

Comment: Pretty sure the same problem (same rule applies to) Java... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency

Comment: Wow. so i've been having the misconception the entire time! Thanks so much for correcting my misunderstanding. This definitely helped!

Comment: You're not the only one. (evidenced by the number of questions I've linked and the responses you see (look at the vote count on some of those!!)  I don't think it's well represented in initial programming classes; and until you actually have to deal with money do you really understand the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128201/discussion-between-alwaysaskingquestions-and-xqbert).