# automatic rounding of float field when executing select statement with php 5.5.19 and mysqlnd

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table which contain a float field ('ferate') and I have set the length to 15 and precision to 2. Whenever I execute a select statement like so, it returns a whole number. I would like to retrieve 'ferate' as a float with 2 decimal places. The default values for 'ferate' should be 44.86 but I am getting 45.

```
public function get_defaultrates () {
    $defaultfuelrates = NULL; // array 
    if (!$this->dbconn->connect_errno) {
        $stmt = $this->dbconn->prepare (
            "SELECT * FROM dffuelexciserates"
        );
        $stmt->execute();
        if ($stmt->errno === 0) {
            $result = $stmt->get_result();

            if ($result->num_rows >= 1) {
                $defaultfuelrates = array ();
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                    var_dump ($row);
                    $tr_dffuelexciserates = new tr_dffuelexciserates ();
                    $tr_dffuelexciserates->dfferid = $row['dfferid'];
                    $tr_dffuelexciserates->ftid = $row['ftid'];
                    $tr_dffuelexciserates->ferate = $row['ferate'];
                    array_push ($defaultfuelrates, $tr_dffuelexciserates);
                }
            }
            $result->free();    
        }
        $stmt->close();
    }
    return $defaultfuelrates;
}
```

Comment: 44.86? is it save in db table field `ferate`?  try once `$tr_dffuelexciserates->ferate = (float)$row['ferate'];`

Comment: yes, 44.86 is the value stored in the db table in 'ferate' field. the dump result of $row shows that it is  45. Also, casting float does not work. here's the dump. 
`array (size=3)
  'dfferid' => int 1
  'ftid' => int 1
  'ferate' => float 45
object(tr_dffuelexciserates)[24]
  public 'dfferid' => int 1
  public 'ftid' => int 1
  public 'ferate' => float 45
array (size=3)
  'dfferid' => int 2
  'ftid' => int 2
  'ferate' => float 45
object(tr_dffuelexciserates)[25]
  public 'dfferid' => int 2
  public 'ftid' => int 2
  public 'ferate' => float 45`

Comment: What is a ferate anyway? Is it like a stoat? See DECIMAL.

Comment: @DatNguyen  try once :- `$tr_dffuelexciserates->ferate = (float)$row['ferate'];` and then check var_dump();

Comment: Anant, if dumping $row shows 45, I don't think casting a float will work? here's the dump of what you have suggested. It remains 45.
`object(tr_dffuelexciserates)[25] public 'dfferid' => int 2 public 'ftid' => int 2 public 'ferate' => float 45`

Comment: @Strawberry, it's a mix between a feral cat and a rat. Which Decimal documentation should I be reading? Can I please have the address?

Comment: See the manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-types.html

Comment: I have changed the type from FLOAT(15,2) to DECIMAL(15,2) and it is working now. I found a good hint from here: [basic link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150274/difference-between-float-and-decimal-data-type). You can store a Base 10 numeric data to a Float field but I think there's a side effect when retrieving a Float value and convert it to a Base 10 value in php using mysqlnd.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question.
I have changed the type from FLOAT(15,2) to DECIMAL(15,2) and it is working now. I found a good hint from here: [basic link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150274/difference-between-float-and-decimal-data-type). You can store a Base 10 numeric data to a Float field but I think there's a side effect when retrieving a Float value and convert it to a Base 10 value in php using mysqlnd.